# Access a Template's Instance scope and inject data

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am looking for a way to access and inject some data into a Template's variable. I want to fetch the data on before route and have it already available when the needed Template renders.

Having a direct access to that scope would be useful. This is my code for that specific template (that is not rendered yet), the variable is **allFriends**

```
Template.FacebookLook.onRendered(function () {
  const instance = Template.instance();

  if(!!Friends.find().fetch()) {
    instance.allFriends = Friends.find().fetch();
  } else {
    Popup.show("Invite your friends", null);
  }

});
```

I found some discussions on the forums and I got as far as:

```
Template.InitView.onCreated(function () {
  Blaze.getView('FacebookLook').allFriends.set([]);
});
```

But I get a `Uncaught Error: There is no current view`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to insert the data inside the `FacebookLook` view? there is no need of `Blaze.getView().`

You can use [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) to archive this.

```
Template.FacebookLook.onRendered(function () {
  var tmpl = this;

  if(!!Friends.find().fetch()) {
    instance.allFriends = Friends.find().fetch();
  } else {
    Popup.show("Invite your friends", null);
  }
  tmpl.allFriends.set([]);
});

Template.FacebookLook.onRendered(function () {
  var tmpl = this;
  tmpl.allFriends = new ReactiveVar;
});
```

Then with this you can access to that data inside helpers or events like

```
Template.FacebookLook.helpers({
  test:function(){
   return Template.instance().allFriends.get()
  }
});
```

**#Edit 1**

Based on your question, what you need to do is this.

```
Template.InitView.onCreated(function () {
  var facebookTmpl = Blaze.getView('FacebookLook') && Blaze.getView('FacebookLook').templateInstance();
  facebookTmpl.allFriends.set([]);
});
```

Note you need to know that this will work only if `InitView` view is wrapper inside FacebookLook view, im talking about this.

```
<template name="FacebookLookTemplate">
   {{> InitView}} {{! here initView can access the parent or wrapping template}}
</template>
```

Comment: What I was looking for is more a call and reach from another scope. I updated my question with the `onCreated` section to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks, my two templates are completely different so no parent-child relationship. I will just vote up for the moment as it might solve my issue